# Iteration of 'window' globals

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

In normal js, one can iterate the window object --

```
<html><head><script>
function one(){
}
function two(){
  for (var i in window) {
    if (i=='one') {
      alert(i);//.......................shows 'one'
    }
  }
}
two();
</script></head></html>
```

But in greasemonkey the 'window' does not hold functions, even functions you defined in GM script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Page 3
// @namespace      http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// @include        http://xxxxxxxxx.net/3.html
// ==/UserScript==
//
function one(){
}
function two(){
  for (var i in window) {
    if (i=='one') {
      alert(i);//.........shows nothing, only iterates native window props
    }
  }
}
two();
```

Yes, I want to iterate my own functions, not the ones in unsafeWindow. Note that the following works, which I don't want to do:

```
window.one=function one(){
}
function two(){
  for (var i in window) {
    if (i=='one') {
      alert(i);//...........ta-da! 'one'
    }
  }
}
two();
```

So what is the name of this global space, how do I iterate it and what is the intent and best practices for this anomaly? Thank you.

Update: 'this' does not access the functions either --

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Page 3
// @namespace      http://xxxxxxx.net
// @include        http://xxxx.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


function do_fixes(){
  var s='';
  for (var i in this) {
    if (i=='do_fixes') {
      alert('yes');
    }
  }
  if (window!=this) {
    alert('window!=this');
  }
}

do_fixes();
alert('this script ran!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global object should be accessible as `this` in global scope and free functions. From the Greasemonkey Manual page on the [Greasemonkey Environment](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual%3aEnvironment):

> Unless the @unwrap metadata imperative is present in the user script header, the entire script is wrapped inside an anonymous function, to guarantee the script's identifiers do not collide with identifiers present in the Mozilla JavaScript sandbox. This function wrapper captures any function definitions and `var` variable declarations made (e.g. `var i = 5;`) into the function's local scope. Declarations made without `var` will however end up on the script's `this` object, which in Greasemonkey is the global object, contrary to in the normal browser object model, where the `window` object fills this function.

The wrinkle is that you need to [unwrap](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40unwrap) the script for your functions to be added to the script global (note global variables are accessible via `this` without unwrapping). Note that `@unwrap` is recommended only to be used for debugging, as  your variables and functions will collide with sandbox variables and functions if they have the same name.

An alternative is to create your own object to use in place of a global object:

```
var global = {};

global.one = function () {...};
global.two = function (target) {
    for (p in global) {
        if (p == target) {
            GM_log("found " +target);
        }
    }
};
two('one');
```

While you could explicitly add functions as methods on the script global, that would give you the worst of both worlds: collisions with sandbox properties and it isn't automatic.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but 'this' does not contain the functions -- I have updated my post to show that now.